# Adding name into database using JavaScript won't work

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database

Html:

```
                        <div class="col-6 col-12-medium">
                            <header>
                                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                                <p>Join the Team!</p>
                            </header>
                            <!--form method="post" action="#"-->
                                <div class="row gtr-uniform">

                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="demo-name" id="demo-name" value=""
                                            placeholder="Name" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input type="email" name="demo-email" id="demo-email" value=""
                                            placeholder="Email" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input type="password" name="demo-password" id="demo-password" value=""
                                            placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input type="password" name="demo-password" id="demo-password" value=""
                                            placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Break -->

                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><button class="primary" onclick="addUser()">Add User</button></li>
                                            <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            <!--/form-->
                        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//function to add the player to the database
function addUser() {
    pId = 0;
    //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
    if (mydb) {
        //get the values of the make and model text inputs
        var uname = $("#demo-name").val();

        //Test to ensure that the user has entered both a name
        if (uname !== "") {
            //check that player does not already exist:
            //Insert the user entered details into the players table, note the use of the ? placeholder,
            //these will replaced by the data passed in as an array as the second parameter
            mydb.transaction(function (t) {
                t.executeSql("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tb_users (name) VALUES (?)", [uname]);
               // outputUsers(_updatePlayerList);
               // outputUsers(_updateVoterList);
               // outputUsers(_updatePlayerVotingList);
            });
        } else {
            alert("You must enter a player's name details!");
        }
    } else {
        alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
    }
    $("#demo-name").val("");
}
```

What is wrong with my code here? I have tried using breakpoints but it doesn't even recognise "uname" as a variable in the developer console. I've included more code showing the inclusion of the function call. I have commented out the form in the html because I assumed it would not be necessary and could be the reason of failure.

Also I opened the database file created and stored by Google Chrome and it had all the correct parameters but none of the prompted information was added.

Comment: `What is wrong with my code here?` - the function is never called - that's one problem  - `it doesn't even recognise "uname" as a variable in the developer console` because the scope of `uname` is inside the function

Comment: ahhh, a form, are you preventing default form submit action? probably not -assuming you're using a form, having only part of the relevant code in the question makes it extremely difficult to provide any help

Comment: Where is this code being executed?  You seem to be using jQuery to get elements, which makes me thing the browser, but then you are executing arbitrary SQL, which really should _NOT_ be the browser...

Comment: @AlexanderNied I'm using Visual Studio Code and DB Browser (SQLite) to run the code.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll add the rest

Comment: As mentioned aabove , If that button is in a form you never prevent the default form submit process. Your page is likely reloading is it not?

Comment: @charlietfl It was in a form but I commented it out. And yes once i press the button the input box is cleared.

Comment: Going to need a lot more debugging detail for anyone to help with. Add some error handling

Comment: @charlietfl such as?

Comment: Is there not an error callback for that transaction? I've never used that api....for in browser I use the built in indexedDB

Comment: @charlietfl I am a bit unfimiliar with this but if you are talking about the errors that are coming through the console, there are no errors that concern this section of the code.